# Unexpected error ')' in: " geom_point()+ facet_grid(dataset~)" > } Error: inesperado '}' in "}" >

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

when I try this lines of code from my r project that asks me to do this:

The datasauRus package contains a data frame called datasaurus_dozen. It has a column named dataset indicating several datasets with points, whose coordinates are indicated in columns x and y. For all these cases, the mean and other statistical properties of x and y are the same. We focus here on the graphical part. Write a function that receives a selection of these datasets, filters the dataframe datasaurus_dozen with these cases and plots the associated scatter plots in one only figure with ggplot2. For instance, if the selected cases are "away", "h_lines" and "bullseye", the function must plot three scatter plots in one only figure. Try your function with these there datasets and, again, with four different cases of your choice. The function must have one only parameter.

```
ex_3 <- function(newtb){
  tb %>%
    filter(dataset %in% newtb) %>%
    group_by(dataset) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y))+
    geom_point()+
    facet_grid(dataset~) 
}
```

this error shows:

> (error inesperado = unexpected error) Error: inesperado ')' in: "
>   geom_point()+
>       facet_grid(dataset~)"
>   } Error: inesperado '}' in "}"

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```r
tb %>%
    filter(dataset %in% newtb) %>%
    group_by(dataset) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y))+
    geom_point()+
    facet_grid(dataset~.)
```

If you want in a single row, you can write `facet_grid(.~dataset)`

---

I tested the remaining of your function and it is working ;)

```r
library(datasauRus)
library(tidyverse)

tb =  datasaurus_dozen
test = c( "away","h_lines","bullseye")

ex_3 <- function(newtb){
  tb %>%
    filter(dataset %in% newtb) %>%
    group_by(dataset) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y))+
    geom_point()+
    facet_grid(dataset~) 
}

ex_3(test)
```

[image]